# How can I implement JWT authentication in a Rails app in API mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that is in API mode.

Are there any gems that provide simple JWT authentication?

Comment: You can check this gem: [rails_jwt_auth](https://github.com/rjurado01/rails_jwt_auth)

Answer (score 1):

Yup, the standard JWT gem is great. Just add it to your gemfile:

```
gem 'jwt'
```

Then I use it as a concern that I can include like:

```
module JWTAuthenticatable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do

    before_action :authenticate_and_restrict_access, if: -> { %w[json csv].include? request.format }

    rescue_from JWT::DecodeError,                   with: :invalid_token
    rescue_from JWT::ExpiredSignature,              with: :expired_token

    def authenticate_and_restrict_access
      return if current_user

      authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |authentication_token|
        data = JSONWebToken.decode(authentication_token)
        sign_in User.find(data[:id]), store: false
      end

      authenticate_user! if !current_user and request.format == 'html'
    end

    def invalid_token
      render json: { errors: 'api.invalid_token' }, status: :unauthorized
    end

    def expired_token
      render json: { errors: 'api.expired_token' }, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end
end
```

You should be able to tailor this to your needs.

Comment: This looks like it should work for my needs. Does `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` check the headers for a token or something? I'm a little mystified as to what's happening under the hood.

Comment: Are you using this with devise?

Comment: I am yes, but from what I remember I think this is pretty free of devise specific code.

Comment: Doesn't `sign_in` create a session?

Answer (score 0):

1. use [devise-jwt](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt)
2. here is an [article](https://medium.com/@hisham.zidan39/rails-api-authentication-3f982c5750e7) I have written including all code you may need and GitHub repo that has a working code